# How do I find 'words' in a string with SQL

Tags: sql

I have a simple query where I want to get all rows with the word 'X5Mdr2' and 'y4M2ra'

```
select id from airPort where dest_name like '%X5Mdr2%' and dest_name like '%y4M2ra%';
```

ex. 
Table: airPort

```
id  |  dest_name                                           | desc  | ...
1   | .. <abcd> *X5Mdr2* </abcd> 28372 X5529 <*y4M2ra*> .. | ..    |
2   |   asdajsdjasdjasdja                                  | ..    |
3   | .. <wxyz> *X5Mdr2* </wxyz> 23812 X5529 <*y4M2ra*> .. | ..    |
```

...

should return id: 1, 3

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You're storing the zip within the same field for the street address?  This sounds like a bad database design if you're storing them all in the same field.

Comment: Is your `ex` an example of all the rows?  Or are they the rows you want?  Because the second one doesn't have a zip which starts with 142.

Comment: If you need to query the zip atomically store it in its own column.

Comment: With the zip in the same column as the rest of the address, this makes your query far more difficult to write.

Comment: I have rewrite my statement to ease out confusions. sorry.

Comment: I think the question is "how do I find 'words' in a string with SQL".

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: you query looks correct.  Maybe try to use sqlfidlle to demonstrate http://sqlfiddle.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[NOTE: The question got edited to a different question while I was answering]*

You're very close.  There's a few small flaws.  But, unfortunately, it'll never really work.

---

Presumably you want to match "123 Main St" and "123 main st" so you need to do the match case insensitively.  You can achieve that by using `lower()` on the `address` and making sure all the letters in your match are also lower case.

```
lower(address) like '%main st%'
```

---

Then there's the problem of the zip code.  Right now you're matching anything with 142 in it.  You want only things which *start* with 142, you don't want 12142 or 31429.  So add a space to the start of your match.

```
address like '% 142%'
```

The street name search can also use this treatment to avoid picking up "Germain Street".

---

Putting it all together...

```
SELECT *
FROM   customer
WHERE  lower(address) like '% main st%' AND
       address like '% 142%';
```

---

This only works to a certain extent.  For example, it will pick up `123 Main St Apt 142, NY, NY 10005` because it's just looking for the number 142.  Or what if they use a comma instead of a space to separate the zip code from the state?  `123 Main St,NY,NY,14205`  Then you won't match the zip code.

If you're using a database that supports regexes you can improve the matching some, but it's never going to be 100%.  And the more complex your matching the less likely the database will be able to use indexes, it will have to do a full table scan every time.

To really solve the problem you'll have to pre-parse your addresses, break them up into their components, and store them.  This is a hard and finicky problem.  Fortunately there's a number of libraries out there to do this, but it depends on the language you use.  That's another question.

Comment: your answer is fine, I just wanted to know if this would work with a big string contains with multiple small sub strings